# Ruby on Rails Apps authorisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization

I am in the fallowing situation, I have one website where users can signup for an account and login, after that they are able to create like a workspace and add applications to the workspace(same concept like on smartphones). Because they will need to buy the apps I'll have to implement some kind of authorisation. I was thinking in generating a token and send it throw a URI to the app backend and if valid let the user use the app. Using this approach means that I need to have 2 token tables? What other option do I have?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that through devise. Here is a simple demonstration of using devise with token authentication. http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/devise-login-with-authentication_token/

Answer (score 0):

i would go for https://github.com/plataformatec/devise in order to save your time